# "or" in shell glob

Tags: shell-script, shell, osx, wildcards

I want to ls the files containing the substring "s1r", "s2r", "s3r" or "s19r" in their filenames.

I'm almost there!

Botched attempts:

```
ls *s[123][9?]r*
```

The above gives me only files including the substring

> s19r

While

```
ls *s[1-3]|[19]r*
```

returns

> -bash: [19]r*: command not found
>
> ls: *s[1-3]: No such file or directory

That is, it does not recognize the or | operator - which makes sense as it is also used to pipe.

How do I ls the files containing "s1r", "s2r", "s3r" or "s19r"?

Comment: I'm on OS X if that matters.

Comment: `ls *s@([123]|19)r*`?

Comment: ls *s@([123]|19)r* gives '-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(''

Comment: Which `bash` version? Are you trying in interactive or non-interactive shell session? http://pastebin.com/VSSTt6qC

Comment: @TheUnfunCat You need to enable the cool stuff with `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: @manatwork Don't wanna make that an answer instead of a comment? Don't forget the `shopt -s extglob` then.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ls  *s1r* *s2r* *s3r* *s19r*`.

If you care about non existing files you can set the nullglob option:

```
          nullglob
                  If  set,  bash allows patterns which match no files (see
                  Pathname Expansion above) to expand to  a  null  string,
                  rather than themselves.
```

If your shell is not bash, there is probably a similar way. Have a look at it's man page.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this:

```
ls *s?([123])r* *s19r*
```

#### For example

I have a directory with the following files:

```
% ls | column
s10r    s12r    s14r    s16r    s18r    s1r s2r s4r s6r s8r
s11r    s13r    s15r    s17r    s19r    s23r    s3r s5r s7r s9r
```

Using the above mentioned ls:

```
% ls *s?([123])r* *s19r*
s19r  s1r  s2r  s3r
```

See the [bash manual on pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) for more details.